# System level metrics per Hadoop task?

Tags: hadoop, monitoring

Is there a way to monitor system level metrics per Hadoop task? I would like to see average CPU/MEM/DISK/NET per every map/reduce task.

I was checking JMX, hadoop-toolkit etc. however I was not able to find right monitoring tool.

I think that I can always set my own counters and dump stats every now and then, but before I proceed I would like to know if there is already something out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the statsd-graphite stack.